# Grails Platform Core, navigation API: easy way to add separators?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-platform-core

I'm playing with the [Navigation API](http://grailsrocks.github.com/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html) of the plugin platform core, that seems to be pretty interesting to organize and display menus.

Twitter bootstrap menus have the option to add horizontal dividers, by adding  `<li class="divider"></li>`

Is there some way to define a separator in the `navigation DSL` and generate this li in the menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this question answered in the mail list: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/platform-core-Navigation-easy-way-to-add-separators-td4638175.html